# ajax scroll position

Tags: ajax, scroll-position

i been implamenting a piece of code in my website that iv found trough phpacademy.org tutorials
the tutorial is 'how to create a like button'. iv got the button to work o.k, but i need an extra bit on function. the problem is that when i click the like button the page pops back up to the top

```
function like_add(id){
$.post('like_add.php', {id:id}, function(data){
    if(data == 'success'){
        like_get(id);
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
});
function like_get(id){
$.post('like_get.php', {id:id}, function(data){
    $('#article_'+id+'_likes').text(data);
});
function delete_like(id){
$.post('delete_like.php', {id:id}, function(data){
    if(data == 'success'){
        like_get(id);
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
});
}
```

is there anything i can apply to this script to save the scroll position???...i have applied save scroll position to links on my website but i cant figure out this:(

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to find the current page scroll position.

```
var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
```

That will return the current scroll position of the page.

Comment: You can save the scroll position before it moves then reaply it. However, after rereading your question again, the issue is more then likely to be an A tag that is firing when you dont want it to. Its probably because your like button is a link with a # as the href. The Function that gets calling doesn't include a e.preventDefault() so the link default behavior is causing the page to scroll to the top because its reloading with the # or empty string. If you haven't looked into that yet, it would be a good place to start

Comment: Hey man....big big thanks, looked into .preventDefault(); and it worked great...it was the fact that it was firing a link...:)..Cheers